# document.getElementsByClassName is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Hy all i m facing the issue regarding getelement by className it didnt work in my vs code also document.queryselectorAll didnt work
i have checked so many times but nothing work
can you guys please look at the  code and guide me
thank you all

```
<body>

<div class="div">
    <h2>heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, esse.</p>
    <button>submit</button>
</div>

<div class="div">
    <h2>heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, esse.</p>
    <button>submit</button>
</div>


<script>
    let m = document.getElementsByClassName('div').style.margin = "200px"

</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a node _list_, not a single one.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName('div')` returns a NodeList, and not a single element. You will need to loop through the result, and change the style for each element.

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
  divs[i].style.margin = "200px"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the document.getElementsByClassName('div') returns an array containing the elements. you should pass an index for example document.getElementsByClassName('div')[0] or if you want the style to apply to all the divs you can map it.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('div').map((element)=>{
element.style.margin = "200px"
return element
})
```